# What does my p-value indicate?

Tags: t-test, p-value

so I got similar results from a t-test output for my p-value 2.50e, but am not sure if it's correct or how to interpret.

```
             11043     3203         
Mean         11333.75   3187.833333         
Variance    264633.0652 203.1014493         
Observations    24       24         
Hypothesized Mean Difference    0               
df  23              
t Stat  77.54556011             
P(T<=t) one-tail    1.2505E-29              
t Critical one-tail 1.713871528             
P(T<=t) two-tail    2.50E-29                
t Critical two-tail 2.06865761
```

Answer (score 1):

In usual computer notation, 2.50E-29 is another way to express $2.5\times 10^{-29}$ thus a very small number, almost zero. So you got very strong evidence, that there is a difference in means that is not $0.00000000\dots$

Whilst this is highly significant, please check, whether you intended to investigate n = 24 in each group or n = 25. I don't know, what computer program produced these results, but it seems as if `11043` and `3203` are really data that a program misunderstood as column names. Obviously, not knowing the software, I might be wrong.